# unable to automatically authenticated inspite of having ACS token

Tags: acs

I am configuring Azure ACS with "Google" configured as IdP in my application. My requirement is that I do not want the IdP login page to be displayed every time I try to log into my application. I have set my ACS token lifetime to the maximum period so that my token is valid for a day.

First time when I log into my application and I select "Stay Signed In" in Google login page, I am able to log into my application. I now close the browser, reopened the application, I am successfully rediercted to the application home page without any credential request. (as ACS internally uses the session token created intenally which will be used in next requests)

But if I do not select "Stay Signed In" in IdP login page, and proceed the same steps, I am asked for credentials. Any idea why is this happening? Is there a way I can manipulate the session token and validate the ACS token which was earlier issued to me ?

Answer (score 1):

When you select "stay signed in" at Google, it writes a persistent cookie, meaning that you'll stay logged in even if you close your browser. By default, your application's cookie is scoped to the session (assuming you're using WIF). When you close and reopen your browser, the original token and cookie are gone. Your browser redirects to ACS, which redirects to Google, which redirects you back again because of the persistent Google cookie. Running your session using Fiddler or HttpWatch should show that, even when you choose "stay signed in", you're still being sent back to ACS and Google and getting a new token.

It sounds like what you want is your RP to "remember" the user so they don't have to log in again within the token lifetime. To do this, your federated cookie (the one with the token in it) needs to be set as persistent, rather than session. If you're using WIF, this can be done using [CookieHandler configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638729.aspx) on the FederationAuthenticationModule (see [PersistentSessionLifetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.cookiehandler.persistentsessionlifetime.aspx)).